# How two APP in embedded Linux communicate with each other normally

Tags: linux, embedded, ipc

I have a main QT GUI App running in the embedded linux system. Now I need to create another APP which is to monitor a rotating knob position and send this information to the main QT GUI APP, wo what's the normal way for this two APP communicate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many options, though using a pipe or socket is common. What you're looking for is [Interprocess Communication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication).

QT has an interprocess communication abstraction that you can probably use to do this:
https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/ipc.html

Comment: Hi Tom, thanks for the answer :) that helps